# Undergrad publishing

Tags: soft-question, publishing

Can undergraduates publish notes (or articles) in journals such as *Mathematics Magazine*, or does one need a PhD? Will the paper be rejected? I could not find any information about this online.

**Edit**: How long does the referring process take? When will I heard from the journal?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I think presenting a poster at a conference is much more common for undergrads than publishing.

Comment: The refereeing process looks at the paper, not (in general) the author. Some journals use double-blind refereeing, so that the referee doesn’t even know who the author is. Do make sure, though, to follow the submission guidelines, and expect to have to make at least one set of revisions.

Comment: The refereeing process can take years, literally. To get an idea, rummage through journals in your area and look for "Submitted" and "Accepted" dates. Or look at their websites, they might tell.

Comment: See http://www.maa.org/columns/resources/resources_08_08.html

Comment: Have you discussed your work with any of your professors? Perhaps they could recommend a suitable place to publish (and whether or not your work is suitable for publishing).

Comment: @user67750 I have, but they never published as undergrads so they did not know.

Comment: I would tend to think that any journal that would have that (rejecting non-PhDs) as a policy (implicit or explicit), would not be worth the paper it's printed on.

Comment: @Gugg I think you are right.

Comment: @Gugg Sometimes referees can be less receptive to content they know has been generated by an undergraduate, not as a matter of policy but of personal attitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely anyone can have work published. I published my first article as a PhD student, so I didn't have a PhD at the time.

Once submitted, the work will go to an editor who passes it on to a referee (or referees) that s/he thinks are suitable to review the article. This process is called "peer review". The referee (or referees) will decide if they feel the article is of sufficient quality and originality to be published. The referee will then pass his suggestion on to the editor who takes the final decision.

Of course, the required standard varies between journals.

Comment: So once I submit a note (or an article) the editor will not reply saying that I should get a PhD and try again?

Comment: I expect that most editors will reject some papers without using a referee if they judge the quality as clearly of too low quality.

Comment: No, I can't imagine an editor saying such a thing. But see my previous comment.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen What exactly do you mean by low quality?

Comment: So you were a graduate student. That's fairly common. But rare are the undergraduate students who manage to reach the standards of usual journals.

Comment: @julien I agree.

Comment: Low quality: Clearly not adhering to a reasonable standard of rigour, or results too trivial to bother with, for example. The point being that there are limits to what you want to bother referees with. Don't let this dissuade you from trying, though. But it is good to get advice from someone before trying to send in your first paper.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It is not my first paper, but it is the first time I am considering submitting a note to a journal such as *Mathematics Magazine*.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Involve](http://msp.org/involve/about/journal/about.html) specifically welcomes articles by undergraduates.

Here is a [link to a list of such journals](http://www.cur.org/resources/students/undergraduate_journals/) provided by Alex J Best.

Of course, you can submit your work to any journal. I am sure there are examples of undergraduate students who published in Annals of Maths. Well, actually, I'd like to see a concrete example.

But it takes very talented undergraduate students to publish in standard peer-reviewed journals publishing original research. It is more likely that undergraduate work finds its place in journals which are oriented towards unergraduate work.

Comment: There is a list of other undergraduate centric journals here too:
http://www.cur.org/resources/students/undergraduate_journals/

Comment: I don't know about Annals of Mathematics (yet), but Feynman published [*Forces in molecules*](http://www.manhattanrarebooks.com/pages/books/680/richard-feynman/forces-in-molecules/?soldItem=true), a widely respected research paper, in Physical Review as an undergraduate. See also [Hellmann–Feynman theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem).